# Is there a way to reduce this further?

Tags: php, variables

I have a php function that I wish to reduce even further.

```
<?='Testing'?>
```

Is there a way to reduce this any further?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

write `Testing` without the php tags. php will only interpret code between php tags, everything else will be outputted without any further processing.

Comment: +1 PHP is text first. Anything not surrounded by <?php and ?> is considered standard text.

Answer (score 3):

Use a shorter word? ;)

Or put it outside the PHP tags (effectively starting and stopping the PHP goodiness).

```
?>Testing<?
```

Incidentally - I'm not overly sure what you want to achieve by "shortening". Do you want to make it faster, use less characters? From that example there - I'm not sure you're going to gain a whole lot from any of these examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the value you'd like printed to a short variable name before the output of the script:

```
<?php
$a = 'Testing';
?>
```

Then echo out that variable in the output:

```
<?=$a?>
```

Can't get any shorter than that.